# Exceed Toolkit TimeSpanUpDown Editor validation

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have code like this 
`<DataGridTemplateColumn >

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <toolkitt:TimeSpanUpDown

                                                  Value="{Binding TimePeriod,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat={}{0:hh':'mm':'ss'},ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" >

                            </toolkitt:TimeSpanUpDown>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>`

So, whenever the user should type an incorrect value in the Hours (say 99) then i want to have some error display scenario where the foreground/background of the Cell turns Red.   Any suggestion will be really helpful.Many THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

to catch null values use nullable attribute

```
private double _lowerSplitValue;
 public double LowerSplitValue
        {
            get { return _lowerSplitValue; }
            set {


                _lowerSplitValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LowerSplitValue");




            }
        }

    public TimeSpan? TimePeriod
        {
            get { 


           return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_lowerSplitValue);


            }
            set {

                if (value != null) {

                    LowerSplitValue = value.Value.TotalSeconds;

                }



                OnPropertyChanged("LowerTimeSpan");

            }

        }
```